# New divs inside pre-existing div with slanted borders

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am trying to make a header as shown in the image attached. I tried the other answers on this website too but none actually helped very much.
I already have figured out the text and logo parts but need someone to help with the slanting div borders.

The effect that I want:

[image: effect I want]

Comment: Do you need a completely customized CSS to get the same as picture, It's not clear to me what you exactly need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```css
header {
  border:1Px solid;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

header:before, header:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: '';
  border-width: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
}

header:before {
  left: 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
}

header:after {
  right: 0;
  border-color:transparent #000 transparent transparent ;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Works like a charm!

Comment: Note that if you want the container to have a different background-color than white, you'll have to change the `header:before` and `header:after` aswell. A better method is to make the border-colors that are not needed transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you have going on in your header, you could try using triangles to mimic the slanted borders;

```css
header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #2c2d2e;
}

.triangle-right {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  
  border-left: 200px solid white;
}

.triangle-left {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  
  border-right: 200px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="triangle-left"></div>
  <div class="triangle-right"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/
This is a helpful ressource explaining this method for CSS triangles.

Comment: @Maharkus Thank you!